# Perform a parent segue from the embedded view controller

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I have this:

- `MyTableViewController` (inherits from `UITableViewController`)

  - It has a dynamic tableview with a few cells (foo, bar, qux)
- `MyViewController` (inherits from `UIViewController`)

  - There are some "show" segues from this controller to other view controllers
  - It has a UIContainerView that embeds MyTableViewController

A picture speaks a thousand words:

[image: embedded uitableviewcontroller]

When a certain cell is selected, I want to perform a segue of the parent view (`MyViewController`)

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
                self.WHAT.performSegueWithIdentifier("someShowSegue1", sender: self)
         }
  }
```

Is it possible? what should I use in `«WHAT»`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `prepareForSegue:` for your embedded segue set the `viewController` in a new property in your `tableViewController`, let's name it `parentController`. And then you'll have just to call `self.parentController.performSegueWithIdentifier()`.

**EDIT**: But first of all, maybe you can use the existing `parentViewController` if it contains the embedding view controller.

Comment: Every child view controller can directly access their parent using parentViewController. We dont have to name it, it's already available. Look through UIViewController header :)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true, but it's readonly... I'll rename it in my answer.

Comment: Indeed using parentViewController was enough. Although the idea was good :)

Comment: this is a great answer, but what if there is data in the child view controller that needs to be passed along in the segue?  how do you pass it?  because the prepareForSegue function that gets called will be the one in the parent view controller

Comment: Does it still work if the parent and child view controllers have different navigation controllers?

Comment: @A.Vin You can set data with the `sender` parameter, and then get it back in your `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: @Jenita_Alice4Real Yes because we're talking about embed segue.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using delegation to solve this problem since the child tableView doesn't seem like it should be responsible for the segue. For example:

```
// MyViewController
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyTableViewControllerDelegate {

    func selectedMyTableViewControllerCell(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        // ... check cell type or index or whatever
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someValueFromCellType", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == myTableViewControllerIdentifier {
            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as MyTableViewController? {
                vc.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}

// MyTableViewController
protocol MyTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func selectedMyTableViewControllerCell(cell: UITableViewCell)
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewControllerDelegate?

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // ... get the cell
        delegate?.selectedMyTableViewControllerCell(cell)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a property. Just this

```
self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook your segue up to the embedded table view controller's cell instead. You can use different segues per cell prototype. This saves you from checking index paths or even implementing `didSelectRow` at all.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4**

Swift 4 no longer has parentViewController. You must use parent to access the parent object and is an optional so be sure to check for nil where necessary.

```
self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "IdentifierHere", sender: self)
```

Comment: `Swift 4 no longer has parentViewController` No, Swift itself is just an agnostic language and doesn't contain anything UI related. This change is not due to Swift 4. It's because the method changed in the framework - in UIKit.

Answer (score -1):

Segue is defined from one view controller to another and is only invoke from the view controller in which it is defined. So you would need to store the reference of the parentViewController.

Like from `MyViewController`

```
if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"embedseg"]) {
    MyTableViewController * tblViewController = (MyTableViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
    tblViewController.parentController=self;  //Storing reference of parentViewController i.e  MyViewController 
}
```

Now you can simply invoke segues like

```
self.parentController.performSegueWithIdentifier("someShowSegue1", sender: self)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should't store the parentController in the child. The embedded table view controller can access its parent by calling parentViewController.