# self.performSegueWithIdentifier being called, but view isn't showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I currently have a `ViewController`, with a `ContainerView` inside which displays a table `ViewController`.

In the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method of my table `ViewController`, it calls the delegate method of its parent `ViewController` (the one holding it in the `ContainerView`) which executes the following code:

```
func communitiesTableViewControllerDidTapDetail(communitiesTableViewController: CommunitiesTableViewController, communitiesController: CommunitiesController, userController: UserController, community: Community, communitySubscriptionDelegate: CommunitySubscriptionDelegate?) {

    let segue = CommunitiesViewController.Storyboard.Segue.DetailView(community: community, userController: userController, communitySubscriptionDelegate: communitySubscriptionDelegate)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(CommunitiesViewController.Storyboard.Segue.DetailView.identifier, sender: segue.userInfo())
}
```

This segue only gets executed for the parent `ViewController`, but not for the table `ViewController`.

The parent `ViewController` has two triggered segues, while the `TableView` controller has none, but I assume that shouldn't matter since it's embedded in the `ContainerView` in the `ViewController`.

Comment: Try debugging to see if the segue identifier is correct, in the moment of calling performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: It's the correct identifier

Comment: Let me see if I get it. You are trying to perform a segue; you have a ViewController with a TableView inside, and the segue is executed when you click outside the tableview, but if you click inside nothing happens. Is that right?

Comment: If I create a view controller with the subclass of the view controller with the container view that holds the table view controller, the segue works, but if I create a view controller with the subclass of just the table view controller, the segue doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have to trigger the `didSelectRow` method of the TableView

Comment: I've already tried that. To make it easier, my issue is nearly identical to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628034/perform-a-parent-segue-from-the-embedded-view-controller